# PHASER ALTARA Struggling with motion paths, enemy ai and animations

Tags: animation, path, phaser-framework, motion

Basically I want to make my sprite follow a motion path and depending on its direction it is going, it will play a particular animation. i.e. moving up will display its back, moving left will display the left side of the sprite and so on.

I've tried for hours but to no avail in trying to make this work. I had some luck using prototype but the final game will be using the structure below. ANY help will be appreciated.

```
/*
 * initalise Phaser framework with width:960px, height:540px
 */
var game = new Phaser.Game(960, 540, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameContainer', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, });
/*
 * Preload runs before the game starts. Assets such as images and sounds such be preloaded here.
 * A webserver is required to load assets.
 *
 * Also in this function we set game scale so it full browser width.
 */
function preload() {
    // set to scale to full browser width
    this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
    this.scale.parentIsWindow = true;
    //set the background color so can confirm the game renders in the browser
    this.stage.backgroundColor = '#4488cc';
    this.game.renderer.renderSession.roundPixels = true;

    //preload images & sounds

    //game.load.image('key', 'folder/filename.png');
    //this.load.image('nazi', 'image/nazi.png');
    game.load.spritesheet('nazi', 'images/nazi.png', 128, 128, 6);

    this.bmd = null;
    this.alien = null;
    this.mode = 0;
    //Use this website to set enemy movements http://phaser.io/waveforms. Export save data from the console log.
    this.points = {
        "type":0,"closed":true,"x":[120,120,260,260,200,180,120],"y":[368,108,108,308,308,368,368]
    };
    this.pi = 0;
    this.path = [];
}

/*
* Add game variables here
*/
var nazi;
/*
 * Create runs once only when Phaser first loads
 * create the game scene by adding objects to the stage
 */
function create() {
    bmd = this.add.bitmapData(this.game.width, this.game.height);
    bmd.addToWorld();
    /*
    For testing
    this.alien = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'alien');
    this.alien.anchor.set(0.5);
    */
    this.nazi = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'nazi');
    this.nazi.anchor.set(0.5);

    var py = this.points.y;


    /*Original Code
    //define the animation
    nazi.animations.add('walk');
    //start the animation at 30fps
    nazi.animations.play('walk', 3, true);
    */
    //define the animation
    this.nazi.animations.add('walkDown', [2, 3]);
    //start the animation at 30fps
    this.nazi.animations.play('walkDown', 3, true);
    //define the animation
    this.nazi.animations.add('walkLR', [4, 5]);
    //start the animation at 30fps
    this.nazi.animations.play('walkLR', 3, true);
    //define the animation
    this.nazi.animations.add('walkUp', [0, 1]);
    //start the animation at 30fps
    this.nazi.animations.play('walkUp', 3, true);

}
function plot() {
    this.bmd.clear();
    this.path = [];
    /*ROTATION CODE*/
    var ix = 0;
    /**/

    //Sets the speed of the sprite
    var x = 0.5 / game.width;
    //looping through plotting points from x and y array
    for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i += x) {
        var px = this.math.linearInterpolation(this.points.x, i);
        var py = this.math.linearInterpolation(this.points.y, i);
        /* ROTATION CODE to follow direction of path*/
        var node = { x: px, y: py, angle: 0 };
            if (ix > 0)
            {
            node.angle = this.math.angleBetweenPoints(this.path[ix - 1], node);
            }
        this.path.push(node);
        ix++;
        /**/
        //this.path.push( { x: px, y: py });
        this.bmd.rect(px, py, 1, 1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)');
        }
    for (var p = 0; p < this.points.x.length; p++) {
        this.bmd.rect(this.points.x[p]-3, this.points.y[p]-3, 6, 6, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)');
        }
}
/*
 * Update runs continuously. Its the game loop function.
 * Add collision detections and control events here
 */
function update() {
    plot();
     //  Reset the players velocity (movement)

    //this.nazi = 'nazi';
            /* For Testing
            this.alien.x = this.path[this.pi].x;
            this.alien.y = this.path[this.pi].y;

            //ROTATION CODE: 
            this.alien.rotation = this.path[this.pi].angle;
            */
            this.nazi.x = this.path[this.pi].x;
            this.nazi.y = this.path[this.pi].y;
            //this.nazi.rotation = this.path[this.pi].angle;

            this.pi++;
            if (this.pi >= this.path.length)
            {
                this.pi = 0;
            }
            /*
            // Flipping the player image based on the velocity
    if(nazi.body.velocity.x > 0){
       //player is moving right
       nazi.scale.x = -1;
       nazi.animations.play('walkLR');
   }
   else if(nazi.body.velocity.x < 0){
        //player is moving left
       nazi.scale.x = 1; //flip the image
       nazi.animations.play('walkLR');
   }
   else if (nazi.body.velocity.y < 0){
       nazi.animations.play('walkUp');

       }
   else if(nazi.body.velocity.y > 0){
       //player is not moving
       nazi.animations.play('walkDown');

   }
*/

}
```